# Помогите с правилами .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Стоит такая задача: есть два домена: site.ru и site.net

site.ru стоит на основном сайте. Так же на этом сайте есть папка site.ru/en, где лежит английская версия сайта. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе домена site.net человек попадал по адресу site.ru/en(то есть на английскую версию) можно на site.net/en (оба домена привязаны к корню одного и того же сайта), и самое важное чтобы в адресной строке человек видел только site.net.

Сейчас такой .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
#адрес домена
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.net$ [NC]
#папка на которую будет происходить переадресация
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
#сама переадресация
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [L]
```

Но переадресация не работает.
Да, и забыл добавить, оба домена работают на https://

Answer (score 0):

При редиректе с `site.net` на `site.ru/en` тогда и адресная строка будет меняться,
если нужно чтобы в адресной строке остался site.net

Могу ошибаться, но вроде нужно что то типа такого в директиве

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.net
    ServerAlias www.site.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/en
</VirtualHost>
```

Если просто редирект (только в адресной строке не будет site.net)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Проект на виртуальном хостинге, соответственно доступа к <VirtualHost> нет. Только .htaccess.